# Best practice to manage app ownership in Slack

Tags: slack

What is the best approach to manage app ownership in Slack?

Currently all devs in our team create their apps under their own Slack accounts. The risk with this is if they leave the company and their account gets closed then the apps they created will cease to work.

This must be a common solution but I couldn't find a definitive document with a good solution.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest for managing ownership of app development.

For this discussion we need to distinguish between

- creating a Slack app
- installing a Slack app.

Those are different concepts which need to be handled in different ways.

### Creating a Slack app

A new Slack app is always created in a workspace and belongs to the user that created it. If that user leaves the workspace (or goes on a longer vacation) the Slack app can no longer be managed.

This risk can be mitigated by [adding collaborators](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps#managing_apps) to every Slack app. Collaborators have the same rights (e.g. delete an app) and will keep their access when the initial creator is deactivated.

As the documentation states:

> - Slack apps are owned and contained by the team they are created on.
> - Slack apps may have multiple App Collaborators associated with it,    and they can review & manage the application record. They can also add or remove other collaborators.

To further mitigate the risk of losing access to Slack app it might be prudent to create a dummy admin user that has to be added to every Slack app as collaborator. That way you won't loose access to your Slack app even if multiple users leave the workspace.

### Installing a Slack app

When the creator or collaborator of a Slack app gets deactivated his app will automatically be uninstalled if he was also the installer. As it says in the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps#installing_apps):

> One caveat: this exception doesn't apply to the folks who created an
> app or were added as an App Collaborator. When they leave, the app is
> still uninstalled. Same goes for when an app uses additional scopes
> beyond the ones listed above, taking on the behavior of a user.

One way to avoid this situation is to use a dummy admin account for app installation instead of the actual user.