# how to display slack app information such as clientID

Tags: slack, slack-api

am not able to retrieve the App basic information for slack-app developed by another member in my workspace

after accessing api.slack.com/apps only my own apps are displayed, how I can retrieve other apps developed by another member in my workspace.

I was expecting to display all apps owned by my workspace

only my own apps are shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the security architecture of Slack you can not see the app details like its client ID unless you are the owner of the app or the app owner has granted you permission. Your role on the workspace (e.g. admin) does not matter in that regard.

App owner can [add additional collaborators](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps#managing_apps) for their app. Those collaborators will have the ability to see all details of an app incl. the client ID.

See also this topic:

[Best practice to manage app ownership in Slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55935369/best-practice-to-manage-app-ownership-in-slack)